# How to use JMeter's while loop to validate a value from a Sampler which need to be executed again?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am doing performance validation of HTTP requests. I have a request which returns JSON values in which, a key's value contains 'Planned' or 'Processing' or 'Completed'.

In first, it returns 'Planned', then it returns 'Processing' and finally it returns 'Completed'.

I use Regex extractor to that particular key's value.

I want to repeat that Sampler until it returns 'Completed'.

Please help me to achieve this using while loop or whatever possible.

Edit: After 100's of attempts only (few mins), the sampler returns 'Completed' until then, it returns 'Processing'.

Answer (score 0):

@Bala

You can implement this using While loop

You have to hit the http request first and extract the `Status..`

now in the while loop use this Jmeter function to evaluate the status `${__javaScript("${Status}" != "Completed")}`
Extract the status again in the loop

Here is the [TestPlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYtBq.png)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What should be the name in 2nd extractor ?

Comment: use same name for both extractors so that it will  override the old value for each iteration

Comment: Its not working. Status extracted from 1st hit remains same. Updated status can be known only when the hit is performed. Does that Dummy sampler hits the 1st request again and again ??

Comment: Yes you have to hit the request again and extract the same  variable with same name in the while loop